# iOS: NSSocketPort, where art thou?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, bonjour, foundation

The developer docs are full of references to `NSSocketPort`, which is supposedly part of the Foundation framework. However, I can't seem to find a header file for NSSocketPort in Foundation. My guess is that it is just Mac docs copied over to iOS, and that NSSocketPort does not really exist in iOS.

My question: does it (read: am I too dull to find it)? And if not: is there an alternative approach on the Foundation level that I can follow to establish a peer-to-peer connection (outside Game Kit, as that seems rather capricious)?

References:

> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/OperationsonNetworkServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002525-SW1

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that it is referenced all over the place but doesn't seem to be a part of the Foundation Framework for iOS.

You can use the [NSStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class for a High Level Socket Implementation (Look at the [SimpleNetworkStreams](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleNetworkStreams/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008979) sample).

I've also *heard* you can use the [smallSockets](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smallsockets/) library (designed for Mac OS, but supposedly compiles just fine for iOS) to wrap the CF Networking classes.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have since found AsyncSocket, there is also a GCD version. Guess I'll look into that.